# Form error handling ajax depending on user input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, error-handling

Couldn't find any valueable answers on this question:
Its a pretty basic ajax form process handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
function functionToUpdate(id)
{
    var data = $('form').serialize();
    $('form').unbind('submit');                
    $.ajax({
        url: "Blahblah.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType:"json",
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        success: function(msg) 
        {
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(req.responseText);      
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Works fine to update stuff in the mysql database. (This is a php file)
I check in the php file the values , with different checks as isset($Post) etc.

So for example:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //do stuff here if button is clicked
}
else{
    // play a nice error message
}
```

How to get this info from the url displayed in the ajax's succes part?
something like this: (For example)

```
success: function(msg) 
{
   if(post = true)
   {
       $('#succesfull').html("Succesfull query").fadeIn(800)
   }
   else
   {
       $('#fault').html("U didn't fill stuff in, failed!").fadeIn(800)
   }
},
```

For example this upset. 
But i just can't get this data from the focused url.

all help is appriciated.

Comment: what's `post` ? you're missing another `=` in that if

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [jquery ajax - how to handle the json response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145043/jquery-ajax-how-to-handle-the-json-response).

Comment: check out for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412890/json-encode-in-php on how to do json queries

Comment: I coudln't really find any good answer yet on this question, i check those, thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process the output of `Blahblah.php` retuned as `msg`.

```
success: function(msg) 
        {
           if(msg=='xxxx'){
             //Do stuff
           }
        },
```

Edit:

I think you may have misunderstood the meaning of `success:` in the ajax call. This is indicating the called page loaded successfully.

Take a look at [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). For this case it may be simpler to use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

or even [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

If you use JSON the output of `Blahblah.php` must be [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Edit:

To return the html output of `Blahblah.php` try something like:

```
<?php
//must be before any output
ob_start();

//php code

$output = ob_get_contents();
$return['data'] = utf8_encode($output);
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Then in jQuery

```
$.post("Blahblah.php", data, function(msg)
{
  $('#succesfull').html(msg.data);
}, "json");
```

Comment: What would be placed in the .php file to trigger this? :P , Sorry if its a stupid question, i don't often work with ajax.

Comment: I tryed, this will return my whole page:P (The page where this is submitted on) , So how to get the data displayed in the php file , also dipslayed here?

Comment: Omg it didn't work becouse data: was called with the variable called... So when i called data it called the data before the ajax form was submitted, so the whole page... What a stupid fault of me.